# After dd, /dev/sdb is not being detected as a block device

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi, dd, block-device

After i `dd` a RPI emmc image, the emmc sometime does not get flashed properly and then I get to see something strange.

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdb*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 306184192 10月  9 15:34 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk     8, 17 10月  9 16:34 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk     8, 18 10月  9 16:34 /dev/sdb2
```

As you can see there is a missing `b` in the beginning of `/dev/sdb` cahracteristics. Why would such a thing happen?

`dd` Command : `sudo dd if=rpi-image-raspberrypi.rpi-sdimg of=/dev/sdb bs=1M iflag=direct oflag=direct`

Comment: Would be nice to see the `ls` both before and after the `dd`, and the entire command.  What OS are you running this on?

Comment: @BowlOfRed Just updated the command

Comment: Could ideally do with seeing the output of the kernel message ring (dmesg) around the time of the dd operation.

Comment: Are you sure that `/dev/sdb` existed before running `dd`?  If that device file was missing, you'd get the behavior that you're seeing.